# Deploying ICO contract to ropsten

Tags: ico, ropsten

I am trying to deploy my ico contract to ropsten for testing and its failing as I said in my [earlier question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41856/reducing-gas-cost). I thought there was something with my code so I tried deploying a contract that [I downloaded from github](https://github.com/Storiqa/ico_smart_contract).

I did not modify anything in the contracts except changing the compiler version.

Then tried deploing and as it truffle reached the point where it tried to deploy the crowdsale contract it failed:

```
Deploying STQCrowdsale...
  ... 0x222d841b9e9628d1b80329491037074ff2105ba27e8f09decfa2a726ece3adb6
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\contract.js:147:1)
    at C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\method.js:142:1
    at C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:89:1
    at C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-migrate\index.js:225:1
    at C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:1)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

This is the transaction:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x222d841b9e9628d1b80329491037074ff2105ba27e8f09decfa2a726ece3adb6

Can someone explain whats happening? Why even an pre-deployed and fully tested ICO contract is not getting deployed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have enough GAS to deploy this . Increase the GAS quantity .

Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]